# Asus TUF gaming X570-WiFi motherboard not remembering RGB settings when powered off, after BIOS update

Tags: bios, motherboard, asus, rgb

I'm using an Asus TUF Gaming X570-wifi motherboard and use Arch Linux.

Before updating my BIOS: Using OpenRGB I could set the RGB LEDs to OFF or any static colour I liked, and when I powered off the machine, after turning it on the next day the chosen colour would remain, and this would continue on until I boot into Windows which resets it (but then booting back to Linux and opening OpenRGB it would be changed back to how I liked). This was working fine for me.

After updating my BIOS: I can still set colours with OpenRGB but if I power down the machine, then when I power it back on, it's reset to default essentially. I have to launch OpenRGB to change it to how I like, every time.

Is there a way to change it back so I don't need to use OpenRGB every time to turn off the RGB LEDs when I boot up the PC? Changing the LED mode from Aura On/Off / All On / Stealth Mode does not help.

Comment: If you simply shutdown and then turn on the machine are the settings saved and restored

Comment: Ah! The settings are *not* saved! I thought they would be as I saw it did save, once, but I think that may have been due to a restart instead of a poweroff. I will edit the question now accordingly.

Comment: Following online advice to change it to Aura Only and run OpenRGB as root, it seems to have fixed it for now. I'll do some more testing to make sure that it's actually fixed.

Answer (score 1):

After running OpenRGB as root, it seems to have fixed the issue. Changing to Aura Only has **no** effect on whether this works or not. I've changed it back to "All On" and it seems to have still stayed when powered off and even with desktop power removed, which is the desired behaviour.

I'm not sure whether this was caused by a BIOS update or by a coincidental update to any Linux packages (I update almost daily, on a rolling release distribution).
I have confirmed the root privilege to be the case. Running OpenRGB as non-root (i.e. normally) and changing the LED's to be on, and then powering off, the lights stay off. It appears that when running OpenRGB as non-root, it cannot write the RGB state persistently to the motherboard, and can only affect it during the current session.

The only difference I can see between running OpenRGB as root and without is shown when running in extra verbose mode (`openrgb -vv`)

Without root:

```
------------------------------------------------------
|                Detection completed                 |
------------------------------------------------------
Skipping zones sizes checks.
```

With root:

```
------------------------------------------------------
|                Detection completed                 |
------------------------------------------------------
Running zones sizes checks...
Zones checks finished: 0 unconfigured zone(s).
```

Perhaps this was the reason it was not persistently setting RGB settings without root.
After reinstalling `openrgb-git` which has installed new udev rules, it seems to now work again without root.